# mce hardware error - what core is affected

Tags: linux, cpu, machine-check-exception

I got a mce hardware error in Linux. I would like to find out what core crashed but I am not able to infer the right core from the error message:

```
kernel: [    1.025641] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
kernel: [    1.025642] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 11: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: baa0000000020118
kernel: [    1.025712] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 MISC d0130fff00000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 600b000000000 
kernel: [    1.025785] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:a20f10 TIME 1634830638 SOCKET 0 APIC 16 microcode a201009
```

What does that mean in detail, especially the last line and the second line? I would assume its processor 11 on core 11.

It's a AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor. I can see that it seems to be CPU 11. But it also says APIC 16 and PROCESSOR 2:a20f10.

From /proc/cpuinfo I get the following information for IDs 11 and/or apic 16:

```
processor       : 11
core id         : 11
apicid          : 22
[...]
processor       : 8
core id         : 8
apicid          : 16
```

lstopo/hwloc shows the following:

```
┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐
│ Core L#0    │  │ Core L#1    │  │ Core L#2    │  │ Core L#3    │  │ Core L#4    │  │ Core L#5    │  │ Core L#6    │  │ Core L#7    │
│             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │
│ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │
│ │ PU L#0  │ │  │ │ PU L#2  │ │  │ │ PU L#4  │ │  │ │ PU L#6  │ │  │ │ PU L#8  │ │  │ │ PU L#10 │ │  │ │ PU L#12 │ │  │ │ PU L#14 │ │
│ │   P#0   │ │  │ │   P#1   │ │  │ │   P#2   │ │  │ │   P#3   │ │  │ │   P#4   │ │  │ │   P#5   │ │  │ │   P#6   │ │  │ │   P#7   │ │
│ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │
│ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │
│ │ PU L#1  │ │  │ │ PU L#3  │ │  │ │ PU L#5  │ │  │ │ PU L#7  │ │  │ │ PU L#9  │ │  │ │ PU L#11 │ │  │ │ PU L#13 │ │  │ │ PU L#15 │ │
│ │  P#16   │ │  │ │  P#17   │ │  │ │  P#18   │ │  │ │  P#19   │ │  │ │  P#20   │ │  │ │  P#21   │ │  │ │  P#22   │ │  │ │  P#23   │ │
│ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │
└─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘                                                                                                                
┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌─────────────┐
│ Core L#8    │  │ Core L#9    │  │ Core L#10   │  │ Core L#11   │  │ Core L#12   │  │ Core L#13   │  │ Core L#14   │  │ Core L#15   │
│             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │  │             │
│ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │
│ │ PU L#16 │ │  │ │ PU L#18 │ │  │ │ PU L#20 │ │  │ │ PU L#22 │ │  │ │ PU L#24 │ │  │ │ PU L#26 │ │  │ │ PU L#28 │ │  │ │ PU L#30 │ │
│ │   P#8   │ │  │ │   P#9   │ │  │ │  P#10   │ │  │ │  P#11   │ │  │ │  P#12   │ │  │ │  P#13   │ │  │ │  P#14   │ │  │ │  P#15   │ │
│ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │
│ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │  │ ┌─────────┐ │
│ │ PU L#17 │ │  │ │ PU L#19 │ │  │ │ PU L#21 │ │  │ │ PU L#23 │ │  │ │ PU L#25 │ │  │ │ PU L#27 │ │  │ │ PU L#29 │ │  │ │ PU L#31 │ │
│ │  P#24   │ │  │ │  P#25   │ │  │ │  P#26   │ │  │ │  P#27   │ │  │ │  P#28   │ │  │ │  P#29   │ │  │ │  P#30   │ │  │ │  P#31   │ │
│ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │  │ └─────────┘ │
└─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘  └─────────────┘
```

Which one is the correct one? Is it the P# or L# number of the PU? It could be Core 5 (L#11) or Core 11 (P#11) or Core 0 (P#16) or Core 8 (L#16)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: after some more mce errors I am sure that it is the physical processing unit number (P#).